# python split string IndexError

Tags: python, string

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("emaillist.txt"):
        line=line.rstrip('\n\r ')
        line= line.split('=')
        newlin = line[1]
```

why is this not valid?  I am trying to break up the nasty looking line of text and make something useful out of it?  Doesnt the split() function produce a list, which you can address via list[x] ?

Thanks!!!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./clean.py", line 8, in <module>
    newlin = line[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: guys, lol, im not a spammer btw, exporting things form mailman and importing into phplist

Comment: does every line have an equals sign in it?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `line.partition('=')[2]` if `'='` is sometimes missing:

```
>>> 'a = b'.partition('=')
('a ', '=', ' b')
>>> 'a'.partition('=')
('a', '', '')
```

Compare it to `split()`:

```
>>> 'a = b'.split('=')
['a ', ' b']
>>> 'a'.split('=')
['a']
```

Comment: Bingo.  That was one of the motivations for introducing str.partition() to Python.  Since you always know that it produces a three-tuple, it is easier to work with than str.split() for applications such as this.

Answer (score 1):

> Doesnt the split() function produce a list, which you can address via list[x] ?

Yes. But if the list only has one element then you can't index it with anything non-negative other than `0`.

```
>>> 'foo'.split('=')
['foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see how many parts the line was split into first:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("emaillist.txt"):
    line = line.rstrip('\n\r ').split('=')
    if len(line) > 1:
        newline = line[1]
        # ...
    else:
        # do something else...
```

---

Or, in 1 line (`[line.rstrip('\n\r ').split('=')[1] for line in fileinput.input("emaillist.txt") if len(line.rstrip('\n\r ').split('=')) > 1]`):

emaillist.txt:

> Email1=123@bob.com 
>   email2=abc@123.com

```
emails = [line.rstrip('\n\r ').split('=')[1] for line in fileinput.input("emaillist.txt") if len(line.rstrip('\n\r ').split('=')) > 1]
print emails
['123@bob.com', 'abc@123.com']
```